# ACSL Counting Unique Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve an ACSL Junior Division practice problem, [here is the prompt](http://www.datafiles.acsl.org/samples/contest4/c_4_duplicates_jr.pdf).

I am stuck on trying to see all the unique characters that have occupied a single index in a list. Here is my code so far.

```
idk = ["C", "E", "M", "O", "P", "R", "T"]
idk3 = []
idk2 = "computer"
idk2 = idk2.upper()
idk2 = idk2.strip()
for i in idk2:
    if i in idk:
        index = idk.index(i)
        idk.insert(index, i)
    else:
        idk.insert(0, i)
print(len(idk3))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow will not offer complete solutions to homework problems, though we may offer hints. Might you make your question more specific? What have you tried? What is your problem precisely?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre] including your desired output. You should include everything necessary to answer the question in the question itself, not in an external link. For more tips, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) and [ask].

Comment: `idk3` is unused. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As it is a challenge i tried, but i still don't get the expected results as in the exercice...It will work sometimes and sometimes not... I guess i'm on the right way...

```
x=0
while x<1: #Test on 1 loop only
    l1 = ["C", "E", "M", "O", "P", "R", "T", "U"]
    count=1 #because of initial list
    new_input=input("Enter 'N String' ?")#Input format N:int+space+string
    up=new_input.upper()#Chars to uppercase
    splited_list=list(up)#String to list of char
    
    #Index N
    index=int(splited_list[0])#store index N

    #Separated letters
    letters=[c for c in splited_list if c.isalpha()]

    for letter in letters:
        if letter in l1:
            if l1.index(letter)<=index:
                count+=1
            l1.insert(l1.index(letter),letter)
        else:
            l1.append(letter)
            l1=sorted(l1)
            if l1.index(letter)<=index:
                count+=1
    
    print(x,"count: "+str(count))   
    x+=1
```

Exercice input / output :

```
2 Computer / 1. 3
2 COMPUTER bat / 2. 5
3 COMPUTER / 3. 2
4 ACSL is fun / 4. 3
9 the xylophone / 5. 4
```

My input / output :

```
2 Computer / 1.3
2 COMPUTER bat / 2.5
3 COMPUTER / 3.4
4 ACSL is fun / 4.6
9 the xylophone / 5.11
```

I don't understand as i think my counts are good.